# Query on defining a property in a class

Tags: c#, mvvm, lambda

What is the meaning of the below line of code in c#?

```
public new SummaryViewModel ViewModel => (SummaryViewModel)base.ViewModel;
```

Is this a MVVM way of declaring the property?

I was not able to under the meaning of this line.

Is it similar to the below line,

```
public SummaryViewModel ViewModel = new SummaryViewModel();
```

Comment: What's your question? one is cast type another create an instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's similar to

```
public new SummaryViewModel ViewModel 
{
    get
    {
        return (SummaryViewModel)base.ViewModel;
    }
}
```

Using [Expression-bodied properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members#property-get-statements). [New](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) introduces a new method hiding the base one.

```
public SummaryViewModel ViewModel = new SummaryViewModel();
```

declares a `SummaryViewModel` field and initializes its value. It's not a property.